# How to keep the Toggle button on when switching pages

Tags: ionic4, ion-toggle

what I want is that when I click on the toggle button to change to true it should stay on true {edit} Meaning when I click on the toggle/switch it updates the default value to true so when the page is refreshed the toggle is still on true untill I click on it again to update back to false.

And on a separate page it will show example:

Front door: Active.   (Toggle on).

Front door: Inactive (Toggle off).

//as much as I have so far

HTML

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Front Door</ion-label>
   <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="fdoor" (click)="toggle()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

Ts

```
toggle() {
    //attempt to figure this out
     If(this.fdoor = true) {
        This.fdoor = true) } //I relized that this doesn't do anything but set it back to false so I feel dumb
}
```

Comment: can you post some of your code or a stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah did an update last night on the question.